# An internal error occurred while creating a Google Cloud Storage bucket, deploying from Visual Studio - ASP.NET Core

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, asp.net-core

I'm getting "internal error occurred while creating a Google Cloud Storage bucket" errors when I try to publish an App Engine App from Visual Studio 19. (It also fails with the exact same error when trying to publish from shell).

From what I can find here and elsewhere, theres a "quick fix" to this, using

```
gcloud config set app/use_deprecated_preparation True
```

but that returns

```
Section [app] has no property [use_deprecated_preparation]
```

I'm pretty confident this has to do with role settings.

I've set permissions in IAM; App Engine default service account has the roles Editor, Service Account Token Creator and Storage Object Creator. I personally have the role of Owner.

Can someone point me in the direction of what I'm missing in roles?

Comment: I couldnt find that property in the gcloud docs, maybe is deprecated. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set#SECTIONWhich error message do you get at publish with gcloud command line?

Try to use the Storage Admin role for the service account.

Comment: Thanks, Mario - I've tried this setting on several service accounts, and none of them seem to work, though. I'll keep looking into IAM, though.